# QAbstractSpinBox - indexChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4

I need to browse `QList<QString>` with `QAbstractSpinBox`. I was looking for `indexChanged()` or similar signal, but didn't find it. It seems I have to hold current index in my derived class. However, I still cannot find the increment/decrement requests, nor the increment/decrement buttons to which I would connect slots. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. Why don't you use a QComboBox for this purpose ?

Comment: @vizhanyolajos Maybe I could have used a `QComboBox`, but I've made a custom widget that holds the `QPushButton`s and a `QLineEdit` and also emits signals when I click these buttons.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to help, but for that, first I should know what's the point of this task ? Or have you find a good answer ?

Comment: @vizhanyolajos I needed a widget for my program - something like the tooltip, where you browse the signatures of the function overloads, when a  cursor is in the argument list (in c++ for example) - but this one is a widget. No, I haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, after I see what you wanted to do, here is a code for you :).

You needed to override the `virtual void stepBy( int aSteps )` and the `virtual StepEnabled stepEnabled() const` function for your purpose.

```
// Header.
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractSpinBox>

class StringSpinBox : public QAbstractSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StringSpinBox( QWidget* aParent = nullptr );
    ~StringSpinBox();

    void setStrings( const QStringList& aStrings );

    virtual void stepBy( int aSteps ) override;

protected:
    virtual StepEnabled stepEnabled() const override;

private:
    QStringList m_Strings;
    int         m_CurrentIndex;
};

// Source.
#include "StringSpinBox.h"

#include <QLineEdit>

StringSpinBox::StringSpinBox( QWidget* aParent /*= nullptr*/ )
    : QAbstractSpinBox( aParent )
    , m_CurrentIndex( -1 )
{
    lineEdit()->setReadOnly( true );
}

StringSpinBox::~StringSpinBox()
{
}

void StringSpinBox::setStrings( const QStringList& aStrings )
{
    m_Strings       = aStrings;
    m_CurrentIndex  = 0;

    lineEdit()->setText( m_Strings.at( m_CurrentIndex ) );
}

//  virtual override
void StringSpinBox::stepBy( int aSteps )
{
    m_CurrentIndex += aSteps;
    m_CurrentIndex = qBound( 0, m_CurrentIndex, m_Strings.size() - 1 );
    lineEdit()->setText( m_Strings.at( m_CurrentIndex ) );
}

//  protected virtual override
QAbstractSpinBox::StepEnabled StringSpinBox::stepEnabled() const
{
    StepEnabled enabled = StepUpEnabled | StepDownEnabled;
    if ( qBound( 0, m_CurrentIndex, m_Strings.size() - 1 ) == 0 )
    {
        enabled ^= StepDownEnabled;
    }
    if ( qBound( 0, m_CurrentIndex, m_Strings.size() - 1 ) == m_Strings.size() - 1 )
    {
        enabled ^= StepUpEnabled;
    }
    return enabled;
}

// For demo purpose.
#include "StringSpinBox.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    StringSpinBox stringSpinBox;
    stringSpinBox.setStrings( QStringList() << "Foo" << "Bar" << "Pig" );
    stringSpinBox.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried it on Windows 8.1 with Qt 5.4.1 and it worked fine. I hope it will be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can override an event method and then get the value in the QLineEdit using lineEdit->getText().

Something like:

```
#include <QAbstractSpinBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <iostream>


class mySpin : public QAbstractSpinBox
{

public:

    void changeEvent( QEvent* e ) override
    {
        QLineEdit* edit = lineEdit();

        //Do something with the string         
        std::cout << edit->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Other events to consider, from the docs found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qabstractspinbox.html#signals):

```
virtual void    changeEvent ( QEvent * event )
virtual void    closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )
virtual void    contextMenuEvent ( QContextMenuEvent * event )
virtual void    focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )
virtual void    focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )
virtual void    hideEvent ( QHideEvent * event )
virtual void    keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
virtual void    keyReleaseEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
virtual void    mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
virtual void    mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
virtual void    mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
virtual void    paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event )
virtual void    resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event )
virtual void    showEvent ( QShowEvent * event )
virtual void    timerEvent ( QTimerEvent * event )
virtual void    wheelEvent ( QWheelEvent * event )
```

Comment: How do I know, whether one of the buttons has been pressed? Sorry, you haven't told me anything.

Comment: The documentation page has everything you need. What have you tried?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using QAbstractSpinBox instead of QSpinBox?